# Why is this expression so common in statistics and machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, covariance, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

I am talking about the expression $x^{T}Ax$. And, this is usually followed up  mostly with some relevance to eigen values and eigen vectors. I have seen it in several problems, theoretical discussions and a whole lot of other places. Can anyone give an insightful explanation about this?

Comment: It is common throughout mathematics: it is a *quadratic form*.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) states "Quadratic forms occupy a central place in various branches of mathematics, including number theory, linear algebra, group theory (orthogonal group), differential geometry (Riemannian metric, second fundamental form), differential topology (intersection forms of four-manifolds), and Lie theory (the Killing form)."

Comment: Don't know if it's a correct way to put it, but is there some geometrical significance that can be inferred generally? Rotation or something else?

Comment: To answer that, pursue the references to linear algebra, group theory, differential geometry, differentiable topology, and Lie Theory: they all concern some form of geometry.  (So do the number theory applications, for that matter, because they can be understood geometrically, too--it's just not as obvious.)